# C++ - constness of template type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I have the following code snippet.

```
template<typename T>
void test3(const T& x)
{
    std::cout << std::is_const_v<T> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_reference_v<decltype(x)> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_const_v<decltype(x)> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    int& rx = x;
    const int cx = 5;
    const int& crx = 5;
    
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    {
        test3(x);
        test3(rx);
        test3(cx);
        test3(crx);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The statement `std::is_const_v<decltype(x)>` yields false for all calls of the `test3(const T& x)` function. My understanding was since the const qualifier is specified as part of the function argument, this statement would yield true, but it prints false every time. Wanted to ask why this is the case and/or if I am missing something?

Comment: `error: ‘is_const_v’ is not a member of ‘std’` Please post a [mcve] with all necessary #include.

Comment: the first problem is that `T` is `int` in all cases https://godbolt.org/z/3x1x5dcYY.

Comment: " understanding was since the const qualifier is specified as part of the function argument, this statement would yield true," thats wrong. If  `const T&` is `const int&` then `T` is just `int`

Comment: See the **note** on `is_const`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const

Comment: I understand `T` is `int` in all cases, so `std::is_const_v<T>` yields false in all cases. The part I don't understand is why `std::is_const<decltype(x)>` yield `false` in all cases.